# how to cut off the text when it exceed the width of a div

Tags: html, css

I have a div which is 300px width, when I fill text in it, only when the user type a normal text like, "Hello, would,my name is kesong", and if the sentence is too long, it would automatically start in the next line, because the div can detect whether the last word can be hold in the same line or not.However, if the user enter something like a every long text without any space between them, like "HELLOWOLRDTHISISKESONGHELLOWOLRDTHISISKESONG..." which exceeds the width of the div, the text would not be cut off and would be displayed beyond the div at the same line.

Comment: `word-wrap` is what you want.

Comment: dont forget overflow:hidden

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Take a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yM2vL/1/

basically, you need to set

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

in CSS (or hard-code the style, but CSS is cleaner). If you want to completely cut the text off, use `clip` instead of `ellipsis`.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow for other options

Comment: Or better, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) since [w3schools](http://w3fools.com) often has outright incorrect information.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **text-overflow** CSS property to set how hidden overflow content is signaled to users. It can be clipped, display an **ellipsis** ('…'), or display a custom string.

> The text-overflow property **doesn't force an overflow to occur**. *To make text overflow its container you have to set other CSS properties*: **overflow** and **white-space**.

### For example

```css
div{ 
  width:250px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;    
}
```

```html
<div style="padding:5px 10px 1px 10px;background-color:#b1dbe7">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris rhoncus lobortis 
</div>
```

**Note**: for more information [click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a combination of the [`word-wrap`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp) and [`white-space`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) CSS properties.

Here's a potential solution (*heavily inspired* by the following Compass [mixin](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/typography/text/force-wrap/)):

```
div {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: pre;
  // CSS 2.0
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  // CSS 2.1
  white-space: pre-line;
  // CSS 3.0
  white-space: -pre-wrap;
  // Opera 4-6
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
  // Opera 7
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
  // Mozilla
  white-space: -hp-pre-wrap;
  // HP Printers
}
```

If you want to actually cut off the text in certain situations (i.e. long words with no spaces) but wrap the text in other situations (i.e many words with spaces), then that'll be a quite a bit more involved. I don't think there's a pure-CSS only solution for that scenario, and you'll likely need a combination of Javascript and the CSS [text-overflow property with ellipsis](http://mattsnider.com/css-string-truncation-with-ellipsis/).