# How to make input type text show last letters of string when text size exceeds width of input?

Tags: html, css

```
<input type="text" style="width:90px" value="This is a text for student with code: 30001"/></br>
<input type="text" style="width:90px" value="This is a text for student with code: 30002"/></br>
<input type="text" style="width:90px" value="This is a text for student with code: 30003"/></br>
```

I have several inputs with limited width containing some text which last letters of texts are more important to be visible.

How can I make my inputs to show last words?

I tried:

```
input{
  text-align:right
}
```

But it was not helpful.

[Please see this ample code.](https://jsfiddle.net/0cjn7fb3/)

[image]

Comment: You can get the answer to this question over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22393485/how-to-cut-off-the-text-when-it-exceed-the-width-of-a-div)

Comment: not exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: ok, so can you please make it more descriptive and specific.

Answer (score 1):

**You can do this using Javascript.**

I use a helper function that will determine the ***width*** of text using its *font-type, font-size and* the *text string*. We get these using `getComputedStyle()`, this allows you to get the style directly from the CSS without having to add it statically and then pass those into the function. Apply the outcome of this function to a variable called ***textWidth***.

Use this along with the input elements `getComputedStyle(e.target).width` set in CSS in a **conditional** and set it to ***elWidth***. Then we run our main function `displayText()` through an ***eventListener*** and listen for the ***event***, use the `event.target` to get the inputs width and run these through a conditional to see if the `textWidth` is greater than the `elWidth`.

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input')

const units = ['em', 'px', 'cm', 'mm', 'in', 'pt', 'pc', '%', 'rem']

function determineTextWidth(txt, family, size) {
  if (determineTextWidth.c === undefined) {
    determineTextWidth.c = document.createElement('canvas');
    determineTextWidth.ctx = determineTextWidth.c.getContext('2d');
  }
  const fontspec = `${size} ${family}`;
  if (determineTextWidth.ctx.font !== fontspec)
    determineTextWidth.ctx.font = fontspec;
  return determineTextWidth.ctx.measureText(txt).width;
}

function displayText(e) {
  const fontSize = getComputedStyle(e.target).fontSize
  const fontFamily = getComputedStyle(e.target).fontFamily
  const textWidth = determineTextWidth(e.target.value, fontFamily, fontSize)
  const elWidth = getComputedStyle(e.target).width
  units.forEach(unit=>{
    if(elWidth.includes(unit)){
      textWidth > elWidth.split(unit)[0] ? 
    e.target.nextElementSibling.innerText = e.target.value : e.target.nextElementSibling.textContent = null
    }
  })
  
}


inputs.forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('keyup', displayText)
})
```

```css
.input {
  font-size: 12pt;
  width: 150px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.display {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  color: darkgreen;
}
```

```html
Enter input: <input class="input" type="text"> <span class="display"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `style="direction: rtl;"` to the input tag if you don't mind letters start appearing from the right.

Comment: I think the concern is how to trim and show the last letters of the string

Comment: So does he not need whatever letters that are not able to be contained into the field? I'm confused now.

Comment: Yes, that's why I need this question to be a bit more specific.

Comment: I don't want to change value of input. I just want end of line to be visible instead of start of line. I tried `direction: rtl` but when using special characters like '\' the result will be different from original text.